# How can I change the color of an icon when a checkbox is checked using Tailwind?

Tags: html, css-selectors, tailwind-css

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="darkmode-toggle" class="peer invisible h-0 w-0" />
<label for="darkmode-toggle" class="btn-toggle group">
    <svg class="icon absolute">
        <use href="../../assets/icons/spirit.svg#sun" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon absolute  group-[peer-checked]:fill-secondary-dark-300">
        <use href="../../assets/icons/spirit.svg#moon" />
    </svg>
</label>
```

In the given HTML code (using Tailwind CSS), I want to change the color of the icon when the associated input checkbox is checked.

The attempted selector used is `group-[peer-checked]:fill-secondary-dark-300`. However, the desired icon color change is not happening.

How can I achieve the desired result of changing the color of the icon when the input checkbox is checked using the provided selector?

This is what I want to achieve with this selector:

- group (select the parent "label")
- [peer-checked] (when the sibling of the label "input" is checked)
- fill-secondary-dark-300: change the icon color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using `group-[.peer:checked+&]:`:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'secondary-dark-300': 'red',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="darkmode-toggle" class="peer invisible h-0 w-0" />
<label for="darkmode-toggle" class="btn-toggle group">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
    <path d="M12 2.25a.75.75 0 01.75.75v2.25a.75.75 0 01-1.5 0V3a.75.75 0 01.75-.75zM7.5 12a4.5 4.5 0 119 0 4.5 4.5 0 01-9 0zM18.894 6.166a.75.75 0 00-1.06-1.06l-1.591 1.59a.75.75 0 101.06 1.061l1.591-1.59zM21.75 12a.75.75 0 01-.75.75h-2.25a.75.75 0 010-1.5H21a.75.75 0 01.75.75zM17.834 18.894a.75.75 0 001.06-1.06l-1.59-1.591a.75.75 0 10-1.061 1.06l1.59 1.591zM12 18a.75.75 0 01.75.75V21a.75.75 0 01-1.5 0v-2.25A.75.75 0 0112 18zM7.758 17.303a.75.75 0 00-1.061-1.06l-1.591 1.59a.75.75 0 001.06 1.061l1.591-1.59zM6 12a.75.75 0 01-.75.75H3a.75.75 0 010-1.5h2.25A.75.75 0 016 12zM6.697 7.757a.75.75 0 001.06-1.06l-1.59-1.591a.75.75 0 00-1.061 1.06l1.59 1.591z" />
  </svg>
 
  <svg class="w-6 h-6 group-[.peer:checked+&]:fill-secondary-dark-300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9.528 1.718a.75.75 0 01.162.819A8.97 8.97 0 009 6a9 9 0 009 9 8.97 8.97 0 003.463-.69.75.75 0 01.981.98 10.503 10.503 0 01-9.694 6.46c-5.799 0-10.5-4.701-10.5-10.5 0-4.368 2.667-8.112 6.46-9.694a.75.75 0 01.818.162z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I want. But can you explain how this selector works and why my solution is wrong?

Comment: `group-[.peer:checked+&]:class` expands to something conceptually like `.peer:checked + .group .class`. Your solution is wrong since it would expand to something conceptually like `.grouppeer-checked .class` which would not select the element under the context that you'd like.